# Communiate LWC to VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I have LWC added in the VF page using lightning out. everything works fine. Only thing I wanted is when I click a button it updates the contact, but it will not reload the page. Since it is inline VF page I would like to reload the contact detail page once contact is updated from LWC.

```
updateRecord(recordInput)
                .then(() => {

                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Contact updated',
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                    );
                    this.loaded = false;
                    this.btnDisable = false;

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error creating record',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                    this.loaded = false;
                    this.btnDisable = false;
                });
            }
```

I know it may be possible with platform events, however trying to avoid that path if there is anything in LWC itself.